# show that $W + V = R^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W = \{{(x,x) /x {\in} R}$ $\}$

$V = \{{(x,-x) / x \in R}$ $\}$
The problem is show that $W + V = R^2$.

But I think $W + V = R^1$ because
$W + V = \{{(2x,0) /x \in R} $ $\}$. Why am I wrong?
Also, Is it a direct sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that\begin{align}W+V&=\{w+v\mid w\in W\wedge v\in V\}\\&=\{(x,x)+(y,-y)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}\\&=\{(x+y,x-y)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}\\&=\Bbb R^2.\end{align}

Comment: Also, it would be direct because only o belongs to both W and V, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So, I believe my mistake was, I got stuck up with "x" while W and V are subspaces. Thank you sir for showing the correct way to solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

For all $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ there exists $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\begin{cases} x+y=a\\ x-y=b \end{cases}.$$
Indeed, solving the above sistem we obtain $x=y+b$ and $y=\frac{a-b}{2}$.

Thus, $(a,b)=(x+y,x-y)=(x,x)+(y,-y) \in W+V$, that is, $\mathbb{R}^{2} \subset W+V$. On the other hand, it is clear that $W+V  \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, $W+V=\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: I kept revolving around 'x' and hence could not think of any other way. Thank you very much for showing other way to solve the problem